# Many to Many Not Respecting Update and Insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to setup and Many to Many relationship between users and roles. I am mostly using JPA Repositories but I also tried using and EntityManger.

I have the following in my main User object.

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "svcAuthUserRolev2", schema="dbo", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable=false,insertable=false, nullable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", 
                    updatable=false,insertable=false, nullable = false) })
    private Set<AuthRoleEntity> roles;
```

And the following in my Roles object

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")

private Set<AuthUserEntity> users;
```

No matter what I do if I make changes to the roles on a user when saving they are persisted and this is not what I would like. I want roles on the user object to be read only.

Comment: did you remove the set method for the Set users???

Comment: Is the set method not necessary when pulling the object as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `updateable` and `insertable` are not working, I haven't used those attributes much.  One possible solution is to make `AuthRoleEntity` the owning entity of the many-to-many relationship.  Just move the `@JoinTable` annotation to the `AuthRoleEntity` and put the `mappedBy` on the `AuthUserEntity`.